# After incorrect installation of Ubuntu, my laptop can't boot any bootable devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi

I tried to install Ubuntu, but the installation was interrupted. Now my laptop can't boot any bootable devices (USB/HDD/SSD, which can be run on another computer).

I have an InsydeH2O Rev. 5.0 UEFI BIOS. I tried load default settings in BIOS, but the changes are not saved. After the restart, all changes are not applied (BIOS settings are not default, it save changes that I made before installing Ubuntu). System Date & Time saves changes after the restart, also I can set the password for the hard disk.

My laptop: Lenovo ideapad 100-14IBY

Sorry for my English, and thank you for your time :)

*After incorrect installation of Ubuntu, I could run Ubuntu USB bootable device, with which I made the installation (only this USB). At the moment this USB device is formatted.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to make sure that your laptop can't boot into any bootable devices by using [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie). Before making the bootable device, make sure to check your:

1. Disk system type (BIOS/UEFI).
2. Partition Scheme (MBR/GPT).

Let me know if this helps!

[Rufus' Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyg2k.png)

Comment: I already did it. It did not help :(

Comment: Do you have windows installed on you at this moment?

Comment: I have a HDD with Windows 10 installed. This HDD runs on other PCs, but is not available for my laptop

Comment: Seems like you got a serious internal problem here, i'm sorry i can't help any further due to avoid another serious problems `:(`.
Of course i can recommend you something. I'd highly recommend you to bring your laptop to local service center.

Comment: Thank you! I brought my laptop to a service center. The specialist told me that the problem is in NVRAM. The problem will be fixed in 1-2 days :)

Comment: glad to hear that! `:D`.